# Ubuntu boot freezes before grub

Tags: boot, 20.04

After some updates in ubuntu 20.04 i reboot the system and it gives me a validation error. I tried disabling secure mode, but when i do it like that the system freezes even before GRUB menu. Trying to hold shift or multiple esc doesnt work. I have dual boot and can still boot into windows 10 with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this new 20.04 problem on both Virtual Machines and on my Laptop. I get a black screen and nothing else before the GRUB menu appears. On my laptop I just kept powering down by holding the power button and after a few tries I got the GRUB menu. That was just dumb luck on my part. I'm sure that this has been a deal-breaker for many.

The same happens on all new 20.04 Virtual Machine installs using Virtual Machine Manager. Again, dumb luck prevails as I choose the "Send Key" Menu and select Ctrl-Alt-Del. The GRUB Menu appears on reboot every time.

In both cases I'm using the standard disk layout with encryption that the 20.04 installer creates.

Comment: I filed a bug report on Launchpad. [Bug 1934690] [NEW] 20.04 boot freezes before grub menu but grub appears after CTL-ATL-DEL reboot.